# JPQL query causing ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. How to fix?

Tags: oracle, jpql

I am trying to run the following query, using Oracle 10:

```
select intel from Intel intel where intel in (select intel from Intel intel where intel.city.name = 'Rome' order by intel.city.name asc)
```

However, I am getting "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis". Clearly, this is not because a right parens is missing. I know that this error is sometimes caused by a bug (http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00907_missing_right_parenthesis.htm), but my version of Oracle is after the bug has been patched.

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Edit**: I know the query is redundant, but I specifically need to test a functionality where I am dynamically modifying subqueries at runtime, and the above is written just to test this functionality in the simplest way possible, even if it doesn't add expressivity.

Comment: This query seems odd.  Why can't you just run the part that's inside the parentheses and get rid of the rest?  Isn't it redundant?

Comment: Yes, I know it's an odd query, but I can't remove the order by clause. This is part of a larger project where I'm testing a framework I made that dynamically builds queries at runtime, and now I'm testing the subquery order by clause. I wrote the above query because it's the simplest query I can write with a nested subquery that has an order by clause. I completely realize it's redundant and doesn't do anything. But it's a test to see whether I'm adding these order bys correctly.

Comment: Nope - they're different. All my tables are suffixed by \_TABLE and all my columns are prefixed by table names, like INTEL_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle parser produces this particular error for any number of syntax errors - it doesn't really mean you are missing the right parenthesis, but that it isn't where the parser expects it to be.

In this case, the error is because of the `ORDER BY` in the subquery.  It is meaningless to have an `ORDER BY` clause in an `IN` subquery, and the parser does not allow it.

If your intent is to have the results sorted, then you want the `ORDER BY` outside of the subquery:

```
select intel from Intel intel where intel in (select intel from Intel intel where intel.city.name = 'Rome') order by intel.city.name asc
```

But based on your comment explaining the purpose, you need to use a different query form to accomplish your test.

Comment: Drat, you're right! (Reference: https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_subqueries ). JPQL doesn't allow order by in subqueries! Odd - I'm using QueryDSL, and it lets me shoot myself in the foot by using orderBy(...) in subqueries. Thanks!